# Correct way to include ruby-embedded javascript in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I hate a form with a jquery.ui datepicker.  I need to have a set of buttons next to the datepicker that would set the date-field to 1-5 business days.  I'm using [business time](https://github.com/bokmann/business_time) to decide which date applies. My form partial looks something like this:

```
#####_form.html.slim##########
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      =f.label :due, "Quote Due"
    .panel-body
      =f.text_field :due  #class="rfq_due"
      =button_tag "1", id:"1_business_day_button"
      =button_tag "2", id:"2_business_day_button"
      =button_tag "3", id:"3_business_day_button"
      =button_tag "4", id:"4_business_day_button"
      =button_tag "5", id:"5_business_day_button"
```

I want to do something like this for my embedded javascript.

```
###js.erb####
$('#1business_day_button').click(function() {
 $('.rfq_due').datepicker("setdate", <%= 1.business_day.from.now %>)
});
```

I'm not sure where I would put this code, the only way I got it to work is when i included it in the html.slim files but I don't like that solution.

Comment: Including it in the slim template is the Railsy way to do it

Comment: I've always assumed that I should never even consider that.  Thanks for the info. +1